# Is there a name for this type of rhetoric?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

It seems that there is a literary term for almost every imaginable rhetoric; is there a name for the following one?

> Natural selection is the blind watchmaker, blind because it does not
>   see ahead, does not plan consequences, has no purpose in view. Yet the
>   living results of natural selection overwhelmingly impress us with the
>   appearance of design as if by a master watchmaker, impress us with the
>   illusion of design and planning. **—Richard Dawkins**, *The Blind
>   Watchmaker*, p.21.

The author frequently gives this example, but he never gives a through example of *what* would make one think that what he sees is actually designed, rather than with the appearance of design. So the rhetoric here is that one gives an argument of type “X does not look like Y” but without ever mentioning *what* looks like Y.